# Get Total in a single line in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a very simple SQL Query which is getting results in the following way

```
COL-A         COL-B 
WINDCHILL   99.998889
WINDCHILL   96.000000
```

Now how i can modify my query so that I get the total in a single line?

```
COL-A         COL-B 
WINDCHILL   195.99
```

The necessary query is as;

```
SELECT ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
        SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
FROM    [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p
WHERE   p.ActualWork > 0
AND ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]), ActualWork
ORDER BY p.ActualWork DESC
```

Comment: How does your SQL query relate to your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you shouldn't have `ActualWork` in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
        SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
FROM    [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p
WHERE   p.ActualWork > 0
AND ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset])
ORDER BY SUM(P.ActualWork) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

its hard to understand how the data you provided relates with the query you provided.

The query seems to result exactly what you need, tasks hours grouped by assets. If for some reason it doesnt, you can use a CTE:

```
with MY_QUERY as (
SELECT ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
        SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
FROM    [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p
WHERE   p.ActualWork > 0
AND ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]), ActualWork
)
select asset, taskHours
from MY_QUERY 
group by asset
```

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged two specific sql versions, but assuming you can use a version that supports Common Table Expressions:

```
with sumTable as
(
    SELECT ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,  
            SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours  
    FROM    [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p  
    WHERE   p.ActualWork > 0  
    AND ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL)  
    GROUP BY ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]), ActualWork   
)

SELECT Asset, Sum(taskHours)
FROM sumTable
GROUP BY Asset
```

Comment: I have tagged 2 versions so as to get more inputs

Comment: Error# 1: Incorrect syntax near '{'
Error# 2: Incorrect syntax near '}'

Comment: Try parentheses () instead of braces {}

Comment: @SmithPascalJr. Edited as per Eugene's suggestion - the braces `{}` around the `with` should have been parenthesis `()` sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way:

```
SELECT Asset, SUM(taskHours) FROM (
SELECT ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]) AS Asset ,
    SUM(P.ActualWork) AS taskHours
FROM    [IR.TimesheetHoursProjectTask] p
WHERE   p.ActualWork > 0
AND ([Task IT Assets] IS NOT NULL OR [Project IT Asset] IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY ISNULL([Task IT Assets], [Project IT Asset]), ActualWork
) as table1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Error thrown is: Inorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.